# IBM API Management Service - Why do I have to create a "Property" to implement SSL for backend services?

Tags: ibm-cloud

I saw the following document on the knowledge center but I could not understand why I have to create a property. I have no idea what value it should be. On the procedure shown on the document, the property I created was not used.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZFB2_3.0.1/com.ibm.apimgmt.apionprem.doc/task_apionprem_SSL_backend_services.html?lang=en

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that it is not necessary to create a property. The rationale behind discussing the property in the document is that, as an alternative to specifying the SSL profile in the connection details, you can create a property that references the SSL profile, and then specify that property in the connection details.

This provides the flexibility that the property can be reused, and if you want to switch to another SSL profile you can just change the property.